# Representar coordenadas eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

estoy intentando dibujar una serie de puntos(coordenadas) en eclipse, estas coordenadas se leen a través de dos ArrayList, pero no tengo ni idea de representarlos en el JPanel, dejo un poco de código:

MAIN

```
public class Servidor extends JFrame {

private static ArrayList<Integer> xPasos=new ArrayList<Integer>();
private static ArrayList<Integer> yPasos=new ArrayList<Integer>();

public static void main(String args[]){
        Servidor fondo= new Servidor();
        fondo.setSize(380,456);
        fondo.setVisible(true);
        TestPane p=new TestPane("/imagenes/planta2.png");
        fondo.add(p);
```

Clase con el JPanel

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Dimension d=getSize();
    imagen=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(url));
    g.drawImage(imagen.getImage(),0,0,d.width,d.height, null);
    setOpaque(false);

    //Dibujar la coordenada en un sitio exacto
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillOval(x, y, SIZE, SIZE);
    g.drawString("Punto de partida:("+x+", "+y+")", 5, 15);

    //Intento de dibujar las coordenadas en un sitio exacto
    g.setColor(Color.green);    
    for(int i=0;i<xPasos.size();i++){
        g.fillOval(xPasos.get(i), yPasos.get(i), 3,3);

    super.paintComponent(g);
}                    
    }
```

Es decir, mi objetivo es pasar los valores de los ArrayList(que tienen valores aunque no se vea en el código) a la clase con el JPanel para dibujarlos, si se incluye código lo agradecería un monton

Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto lo puedes conseguir de varias maneras, pero creo que la más sencilla es utilizar los constructores del panel que has definido. Ahí pasas las dos listas y compruebas que tengan el mismo tamaño y que no sean nulas ni vacías. Si todo es correcto, las guardas en los atributos para más tarde imprimirlas.

Aquí un ejemplo de código que realiza lo que pides (a tu clase `TestPane` yo la he llamado `PointsPanel`).

```
public class PointsPanel extends JPanel {

    private Set<Point> puntos = new HashSet<>();

    public PointsPanel(List<Integer> x, List<Integer> y) {
        if (x != null && y != null) {

            if (x.size() != y.size())
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();

            if (!x.isEmpty()) {
                Integer[] abscisas = new Integer[x.size()];
                Integer[] ordenadas = new Integer[y.size()];

                x.toArray(abscisas);
                y.toArray(ordenadas);

                for (int i = 0; i < abscisas.length; i++)
                    puntos.add(new Point(abscisas[i], ordenadas[i]));
            }

        }
    }

    /* Resto de la clase */

}
```

En el constructor acepto dos listas, pero las convierto a un conjunto de puntos (`Set<Point>`) para tener en cada elemento del conjunto las dos coordenadas, y para evitar puntos repetidos.

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    if (puntos == null || puntos.isEmpty()) return;
    for (Point p : puntos) {
        g.fillOval(p.x, p.y, 3, 3);
    }
}
```

El método `paint(Graphics g)` funcionaría de la misma manera (yo lo he simplificado para no alargarme demasiado) que tu método `paintComponent(Graphics g)`.

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿La clase Points la has creado tú o viene definida en java?, es que he puesto el código y no me da la opción de importar de ningún sitio

Comment: La clase se llama `Point` en singular, y viene definida en el paquete `java.awt`.